# Files without extension not being deployed by Octopus

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, octopus-deploy

We have a file in our built NuGet package `.nupkg` which does not have an extension, i.e. `svgo`.

This file is not being deployed as part of a standard Octopus 'Deploy a package' step. We see the file in the NuGet package when viewing with NuGet Package Explorer.

We've also noticed several other extensionless files in the NuGet package do not get deployed.

We're using Octopus Deploy `3.3.27`, and the deployment target is running Windows Server 2012 R2.

How do I deploy extensionless files from NuGet packages in Octopus?